# Using external trim resistor to control boost converter voltage without introducing noise to the voltage feedback

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, noise

**Requirement:**

- I want to use external trim to control the output voltage. This will modify/replace the internal R1/RV1/R3 feedback network.
- <s>There should be **only one trim terminal** so it should be referenced to either VCC, GND or OUT.</s>
- <s>The circuit does not burn when the wiper is at either either ends.</s>

[image]

**Problem:**

- **FB (pin3) network is extremely sensitive** to noise. Long wire of external trimmer is bond to cause problem.
- <s>To satisfy the single terminal requirement, only R1 and R3 can be replaced with external trimmer. However, if R1=0, the error amplifier will burn. If R3=0, the output voltage will go crazy and burn the entire output stage.</s>

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Swapping RV1 and R3 is the solution to problem 2, and it does not matter if the wiper is shorted to pin 1 or pin 3. In this configuration RV1 is replaced with external trimmer, but the noise problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to problems:

1. Agreed. `C1` is there to mitigate this. If the external trimmer introduces too much noise, you can increase C1, at the expense of step-response performance. Perhaps more importantly you need to consider your external trimmer part of the signal integrity loop. I think by the "one trim terminal" remark you're indicating the rail (eg. GND or VCC) is connected elsewhere. There has to be a loop somewhere, and need to make sure that loop area is small to minimise noise.
2. The four-way junction between `R1` and `RV1` makes it impossible to determine what's actually connected, but regardless, you could wind `RV1` so the wiper is shorted to terminal 3 and fix it there (eg. with glue). That way if you replace `R3` with your external wiper, even if it goes short there is still 10kΩ to ground, as with the original circuit.